# GDB: display function prints my {type}'s address as an integer—would like to change to hex

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I'm debugging on the command line using GDB. I've got some typedef-structs that I'd like to keep track of by using the 'display' command via their address. My command looks like this:

```
display {Link} 0x100103980
```

Where Link is in a linked list. I don't have any other way to access it other than this address.

Edit: Just to clarify, Link is a struct-type, not a variable. There aren't any variable names for my links, just their address.

My output looks like:

```
5: {Link} 4296030592 = {
  value = 100, 
  next = 0x1001039e0
}
```

but as you can see, the address is no longer expressed in hex, it's now in an int form.
I tried using /x but that didn't work either:

```
(gdb) display/x {Link}0x100103980
6: /x {Link} 4296030592 = {
  value = 0x64, 
  next = 0x1001039e0
```

Is it possible for 'display' to show the address in hex? If so, how?
Edit: I'm running OSX 10.8.

Thanks

Comment: Link is a name of variable?

Comment: What is your operating system? What is your GDB version?

Comment: @computer, no Link is the struct-type I've defined.

Comment: you need variable, object if you want to print address however you might try what I posted

Comment: @jxh I'm running OSX 10.8. GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1824)

Comment: have you tried to use print/x?

Comment: Does it usually work except for this time, or has it always failed?

Comment: I honestly think it's like this by design. I was just checking to see if they're any other options. I don't really want to use print; I'd like to see the structs after every instruction. Strangely enough if you call a struct by it's name instead of it's address it will show the address in hex instead of an integer. Bleh.

Comment: Why? You gave the hex address as input, so you obviously know it already.

Answer (score 0):

if you call a struct by it's name instead of it's address it will show the address in hex. Alternatively use `print` to display address of variable:

```
(gdb) print/x &Link     print address of variable Link in hex
```

[GDB commands by function - simple guide](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~jrb/cs201/lectures/handouts/gdbcomm.txt)